# How can dynamic speedometer reflect the speed on User Interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reflection

I am trying to create a responsive and dynamic speedometer. The speedometer will reflect the speed in numeric form, the functionality is based on the number of clicks that user has clicked on the screen.

Hence, the speedometer will reflect a higher speed if the user has got higher number of clicks and vice versa.

***Issue:***

To be able to reflect the speedometer, I have created a canvas to contain the speedometer. The code is as shown below:

```
<div id="speedometer" style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%" left="160px" top="250px">
       <script type ="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           var dialCenter = [129,124];
           var needleCenter = [13,121.5];
           var dial = new Image, needle = new Image;
           window.onload =function(){
               //Find Canvas element
               var v =document.getElementById('myCanvas')[0];
               //Enable drawing object for the canvas
               var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
               ctx.save();
               //create the canvas
               ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);

               //setting and alignment of text in canvas
               ctx.font ="12px Arial";
               ctx.textAlign ="center";
               ctx. filltext("Speed Meter",10,50);

               //center the dial on the canvas
               ctx.translate(c.width/2, c.height/2);
               ctx.drawImage(dial, -dialCenter[0], -dialCenter[1]);

               //center the needle on the canvas
               ctx.rotate(2.3*Math.sin((new Date)*1/1000)- 0.15);
               ctx.drawImage(needle, -needleCenter[0], -needleCenter[1]);
               ctx.restore();
           };
           //Assign the image source 
           dial.src='MeterBar.png';
           needle.src = 'MeterPin.png';
        </script>
</div>

<script>
       function speedometer(){
            ...(Function to create speedometer to by dynamic)
        }
</script>
```

However, at this point, I am stuck in the creation of reflection of the speed when user clicks on the screen.

I do have this idea that:

> On user first interaction with the screen, it will log the time, hence for every subsequent touch, it will log the user interaction time. Hence the formula for me to create the speed reflection will be: ((2nd touch time)-(1st touch time))/(1st touch time) to get the speed.
>   however, is this the only way as I feel that it will require huge memory space and processing space. Is there any other effective way?

Therefore, I would like to ask: How am I able to enable the speedometer to reflect the speed in regards to the number of clicks the user has clicked on the screen? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, you will want to compare the last click time with the current click. Something like:

```
var lastClickDateTime = new Date();

function getSpeed() {
    var currentDateTime = new Date();
    return currentDateTime.getTime() - lastClickDateTime.getTime();
}
```

However, in reality this will give you big jumps in data values so you'd probably want to average a series of the last clicks.